# submit a form data with in a pop up box and display result with in that popup box

Tags: forms, popup

I need to implement a search form with in a pop up  box and display the search results with in that pop up  box also.

I had implement a pop up  box with my search input field and submit button but don't know how to retrieve data with in pop up box after submitting form.

I have some queries like as  follows :-

1. How can i retrieve data with in pop up box , what will be the action for form to retrieve data from.
2. How to display results with in that pop up box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you're looking for. But it should give you an idea and then adapt it to what you need. Sorry for not explaining all this with more detail, i just saw the post so i thought i'd give you an idea before getting back to work.

Form code:

```
<form method="" action="">
<h2>Name</h2><br />
    <input name="name" type="text" size="55" class="required error name"><br />
    <h2>Email </h2><br  />
    </span><input name="email" type="text" size="55" class="required email"/><br />
    <h2>Phone</h2><br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" size="55" class="phone" /> <br />
    <h2>Comments</h2><br />
    <textarea name="comments" rows="15" cols="47" class="comments"></textarea><br />
    <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitBtn" />
</form>
```

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submitBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var email = $('.email').val();
    var phone = $('.phone').val();
    var comments = $('.comments').val();

    var dataObject = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        comments: comments
    }

    $.Ajax({
    url: php/sendmail.php,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: dataObject,
    success: function(data){
             var createdDiv = '<div class="DIVCENT"><p class="dataText">' + data + '</p></div>';
             $('body').append(createdDiv);
        };
    });
});

});
```

If you want to center the div. You'll need some CSS like below.

```
.DIVCENT{
height: 100px;
width:40%;
margin:auto;
}
```